# Override admin local name

Tags: localization

I changed the language locale to Hungarian, but the translation for the singles looks a bit funny. Is there an easy way to override it with my version?

Singles are translated to "Egyedülállók" but that 99% of the time here means a single person and not a single something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add your own translations by placing a region-specific translation file in a `craft/translations` folder. The filename should be named after your locale and return an array of translations.  In your case this may look like a file named:

```
craft/translations/hu.php
```

And within that file, returning an array like so:

```
<?php 

return array(
    "Singles" => "Something Better than Egyedülállók"
);
```

All strings that are identified as translatable in your front-end templates and the Craft Control Panel files, will be checked against these translations when loading a page in your particular locale. Craft's help doc on [Static Translations](https://craftcms.com/support/static-translations) discusses what this could look like in your templates.

---

If the phrase is really off in your language, you may want to reach out to Pixel & Tonic and let them know as well. I believe they welcome recommendations from community members on how language translations can be improved.

Comment: Note: a craft/translations folder is not to be confused with the system's craft/app/translations folder.  You need to add a craft/translations folder yourself.

Comment: It's also possible to keep your translation files somewhere else/outside the /craft folder – just set the [`CRAFT_TRANSLATIONS_PATH`](https://craftcms.com/docs/php-constants#craft-translations-path) PHP constant to your desired path (you can set the constant it in your /public/index.php file, for example).